# Why PHP Ajax Showing HTML instead of Plain text?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Recently I changed my server from Cloudflare to Ezoic CDN. At Cloudflare, everything was working as expected. But at Ezoic, Here is what is happening.

Here is my Ajax request file.

```
<p id="abc"></p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$.post('demo.php',(data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    if(data=="null")
    {
     console.log("No data");
     return;
    }
    
    $("#abc").append(data);
})
</script>
```

Here is demo.php

```
<?php
// database queries.
if($no_row==0)
{
echo "null";
exit();
}
echo $row_data;
?>
```

But here instead of plain text ajax is returning data like `<html><head></head><body>null</body></html>` 
Even where data is present extra HTML(head, body) wrapper is included. It is weird as it was not happening before.

When I added `header("Content-Type: text/plain")` then everything was working as before.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you modify your ajax to include `dataType: "text"`?

Comment: Although there is no reason anything extra will be sent by PHP other than what you asked it for, still, using appropriate mime type (content type) is always a safer way, especially to maintain compatibility with both the serving platform and the client.

Comment: Aside from the issue, it's generally not good practice to be returning plaintext responses. Use a serialised format such as JSON or XML to prevent any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using in ajax call:

```
dataType : "text",
contentType: "application/json",
```